# Can't remove class from an element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following markup:

```
<div class="row">
    <img src="image.png" class="download-image regular-image" />
<div class="options">
     <p>download</p>
</div>

<img src="image.png" class="download-image regular-image" />
<div class="options">
     <p>download</p>
</div>
```

ANd following code to manipulate it (it changes image, basically it's an active state implementation):

```
$(".download-image").click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).next().toggle();
    $('.download-image').removeClass('current').attr('src', 'image.png');
    $(this).addClass("current").attr('src', 'image2.png');
    $(document).delegate('.current','mouseover',function() {
        $(this).attr("src", "image2.png");
    });
    $(document).delegate('.current','mouseout',function() {
        $(this).attr("src", "image.png");
    });
});
```

This code works well, but I'm having a trouble removing `.current` class by clicking on an element. Althrough I implemented it via clicking on any place of the page like this:

```
$("html").click(function() {
    $(".options").hide();
    $(".download-image").removeClass('current').attr("src", "image.png");
    $(".download-image").hover(function() {
        $(this).attr("src", "image2.png");
    }, function() {
        $(this).attr("src", "image.png");
    });
 });
```

This chunk does exactly what I want, but I also wanna have same behavior for active image too. What I tried:
1. Add `.current` to `html` click event
2. Create same function but for `.current` class
3. Use `.on('click', '.current', function()`
4. Going just like this:

```
$('.current').click(function() {
     $(this).removeClass('current');
}
```

Nothing above worked for me. Where I was wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The this keyword in the callback function of a listener has the event attached to it. You want the HTML element. Try this.  $('.current').on('click', function(e) {      $(e.target).removeClass('current'); } on mobile atm so formatting is ass

Comment: Can you verify what `$(this)` resolves to using developer tools? I think I faced the same problem a while ago, in which case `$(this)` was not resolving to the `img` tag, but the surrounding `div` instead.

Comment: @DotBert it points to the event which isn't exactly what he wants

Comment: For the sake of completeness (not directly related to the problem): [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) is deprecated as of v3 in favour of [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 2):

The this keyword in the callback function of a listener has the event object attached to it. You want the HTML element. You can see this in action by logging out the value of this inside of the callback and looking at the object.  Try this to get the HTML element instead:

```
$('.current').on('click', function(e) {      
       $(e.target).removeClass('current');
 }
```

Make note of the argument I'm giving to the callback. I believe this.target might actually be the same object but I'm on mobile atm so can't  verify. You can though, by logging out the values with a console.log(this); statement

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't worked for me. I can get corresponding element via console.log and I can even remove this class via console like `$('.current').removeClass('current')` but it doesn't work inside my click event, neither in cosole or in code

Answer (score 0):

Solution was so obvious that I feel ashamed I haven't tried it before posting my question. I used `.toggleClass()` method and now my `click()` event looks like this:

```
$(".download-image").click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
        $(this).next().toggle();
        $('.download-image').removeClass('current').attr('src', 'image.png');
        $(this).toggleClass("current").attr('src', 'image2.png');
        $(document).delegate('.current','mouseover',function() {
            $(this).attr("src", "image2.png");
        });
        $(document).delegate('.current','mouseout',function() {
            $(this).attr("src", "image2.png");
        });
    });
```

Please note that I use old jQuery, if you're using `v3+`, you should replace `.delegate()` method with `.on()` as reffered in comments.